# Spring-data-redis: Mysteriously stops working after a few hours

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, jedis, spring-data-redis

I have a backend process that uses spring-data-redis. Similar to the [retwis clone](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-keyvalue-examples/tree/master/retwisj), it uses [StringRedisTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-keyvalue/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/keyvalue/redis/core/StringRedisTemplate.html). After about 3-4 hours of running on my Digital Ocean droplet, it mysteriously stopped persisting new keys. My logs indicate that my redis persistence code is being invoked, it just somehow stops working, without any signs of error, at the spring-data-redis/jedis layer.

**Troubleshooting done so far**

1. I have enough ram. Redis is only using up 6mb.
2. I restarted my backend process and everything is working as expected again, key values are being inserted.
3. I checked redis-server.log. It is consitent with my hypothesis of spring-data-redis/jedis failing. The entries stopped at the same time that my last key was inserted. The entries on 08/09/2015 are when it mysteriously failed. The entries on the next day, 08/10/2015 is when I restarted it.

   ```
   [2267] 09 Aug 19:20:51.094 * 1 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
   [2267] 09 Aug 19:20:51.096 * Background saving started by pid 6611
   [6611] 09 Aug 19:20:51.348 * DB saved on disk
   [6611] 09 Aug 19:20:51.350 * RDB: 4 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
   [2267] 09 Aug 19:20:51.397 * Background saving terminated with success
   [2267] 09 Aug 19:25:52.043 * 1 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
   [2267] 09 Aug 19:25:52.045 * Background saving started by pid 6706
   [6706] 09 Aug 19:25:52.417 * DB saved on disk
   [6706] 09 Aug 19:25:52.418 * RDB: 4 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
   [2267] 09 Aug 19:25:52.451 * Background saving terminated with success
   [2267] 10 Aug 05:01:38.204 * 1 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
   [2267] 10 Aug 05:01:38.206 * Background saving started by pid 12252
   [12252] 10 Aug 05:01:38.647 * DB saved on disk
   [12252] 10 Aug 05:01:38.648 * RDB: 6 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
   [2267] 10 Aug 05:01:38.716 * Background saving terminated with success
   [2267] 10 Aug 05:06:39.054 * 1 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
   [2267] 10 Aug 05:06:39.055 * Background saving started by pid 12263
   [12263] 10 Aug 05:06:39.193 * DB saved on disk
   [12263] 10 Aug 05:06:39.194 * RDB: 6 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
   [2267] 10 Aug 05:06:39.258 * Background saving terminated with success
   [2267] 10 Aug 05:11:40.082 * 1 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
   [2267] 10 Aug 05:11:40.084 * Background saving started by pid 12272
   [12272] 10 Aug 05:11:40.342 * DB saved on disk
   [12272] 10 Aug 05:11:40.344 * RDB: 6 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
   [2267] 10 Aug 05:11:40.385 * Background saving terminated with success
   ```
4. My own application logs show no exceptions. There is no logger for spring-data-redis nor jedis either. So they are not throwing exceptions (as I am not catching any) and they have no log output. Apparently the request is being made to spring-data-redis, and spring-data-redis is returning back to my code with no exceptions.

**Next steps on troubleshooting?**

There is very minimal amount of logging in spring-data-redis and its underlying redis driver "Jedis". I've enabeled logging on the 2, will see if that helps when/if the issue happens again.

I've also considered debugging this but I think would rather just switch to a different driver/project at this point.

Comment: Could you do thread stack dump when it's frozen if you mind?

Comment: Did you solve this? Could you post your solution and what your configuration for connection pooling is for jedis.